# Ext.dd.DragZone for a grid (multiple items) GetDragData

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I don't know if someone could help me with this. I've been trying all afternoon and I could not get it right.

I have defined a `DragZone` for a grid...

```
 Ext.define('Timetabling.view.ItStudentsDragZone', {

        extend    : 'Ext.dd.DragZone',

        grid    : null,


   //Tell Ext how to recover from an invalid drop. XY from the dragged data
   getRepairXY: function() {
      return this.dragData.repairXY;
   },


   // To pair together a drag zone and drop zone
   ddGroup     : 'itstudents',        


   getDragData : function(e) {            
   var sourceEl    = e.getTarget(),
           view  = this.grid.getView(),
           rowEl = view.findItemByChild(sourceEl),
           rec  = rowEl && view.getRecord(rowEl);

           if (sourceEl) {
                d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
                d.id = Ext.id();

               return {
                ddel: d,
                sourceEl: sourceEl,
                repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).getXY(),
                sourceStore: null,
                draggedRecord: null
             }
        }                                   
      }
   });
```

If I select just one item from the grid, it works fine. But when I select two or more items and then I click on the Grid selection to drag it, the item clicked in the grid selection gets selected and the other one remains unselected, so I can just drag again one item!

I guess I have to get the grid selection as an element but I don't know how to do it...

I would really appreciate if someone has some ideas on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the extjs 4.1 example [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Darin.

I can't use the built in Drag&Drop from extjs 4.1 because I need to override the getDragData to do some specific actions. The problem is that I don't know how to get as a source element the both items selected...